# Word Offic.js Add-in Runs Another Office.js

Tags: office-js, yeoman-generator, word-addins

I have been developing a Microsoft Word Add-in using Office.js on a mac. I used the yeoman generator to setup the project. Then visual studio code as my IDE The first project runs fine when I use the npm start script to test my Add-in in Word.

I then decided to create another Add-in project again using the yeoman generator. This populates the project with some back hello world code. However when I run the new project I created using npm start, the code that is displayed in the add-in is from the first Add-in I was working on. The title of the taskpane is the name of the new project, but what is rendered is from the first project.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible cause of your symptoms is that the Node server for the first project is still running. Be sure to shut it down before you run `npm start` in the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first and second add-ins are using the same domain, probably something like `localhost:3000` and Office or the browser has cached the files from the first add-in. Try clearing the Office cache. See [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache).

Comment: I cleared the cache through the "clear web cache" commad as well as manually (on Mac) and when I run the add-in again I still get the same issue. I also tried to change port to 3001, but that did not help either. Any Ideas?

Comment: When I connect to localhost:3000 the manifest.xml is that of the first project. I also removed the old manifest from /Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents/wef. I am still confused as to why it runs the old add-in.

Comment: The manifest is sideloaded to Office. It is not hosted in the web site, so I don't know what you mean by "When I connect to localhost:3000 the manifest.xml is that of the first project."  My best guess now would be that you are running `npm start` in the root of the old project. Another possibility is that you ran `npm start` on the old project and you never shut that server down, so it is still running.

Comment: After you run npm start, you can go to localhost:3000 and you will be able to navigate the files that are being run. Manually killing the old node process did the trick, since the old process was still running on port 3000. Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: OK. I'll add a second answer about that. Please approve it so that the question will be considered answered in Stack Overflow's stats.